# Change textcolor of a custom ListView

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview

I created a custom Listview by defining a subclass of `ArrayAdapter`
each item of my listview is a `XML` file that contains two textView's.
It Works fine but now I want to change the textcolor of my list, programmatically. I tried to `setTextColor()` to the textView's but the app goes to force close!.

** textfile_item_row.XML :displaying each list view item **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewItemName"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewItemContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
    android:typeface="monospace"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class TextFile {

public String name;
public String content;


public TextFile() {
    super();
}


public TextFile(String name, String content) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.content = content;
}

}
```

**Here is  my custom ArrayAdapter**

```
public class TextFileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TextFile> {

Context             context;
int                 layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<TextFile> data = null;


public TextFileAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<TextFile> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    TextFileHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new TextFileHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
        holder.txtContent = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemContent);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (TextFileHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    TextFile textFile = data.get(position);
    holder.txtContent.setText(textFile.content);
    holder.txtName.setText(textFile.name);

    return row;
}


static class TextFileHolder
{

    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtContent;
}
}
```

**and in my main activity**

```
ArrayList<TextFile> textData = new ArrayList<TextFile>();
```

.
.
.
.

```
TextFileAdapter adapter = new  TextFileAdapter(this,R.layout.textfile_item_row, textData);
 listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my log cat :

```
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{vakili.ramin.apps.actionbartest/vakili.ramin.apps.actionbartest    .MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:78    4)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at vakili.ramin.apps.actionbartest.MainActivity.showUserSettings(MainActivity.java:235)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at vakili.ramin.apps.actionbartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-06 20:12:47.996: E/AndroidRuntime(652):  ... 11 more
```

mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView                 listView1;
    private static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
    TextView                 tv1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getOverflowMenu();
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    readTextFiles();
    showUserSettings();

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
            String itemName = textView1.getText().toString();
            File STR = new     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/testfiles");//sdcard directory->/mnt/sdcard
            File myText = new File(STR + "/" + itemName);
            StringBuilder txtContent = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new    FileReader(myText));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    txtContent.append(line);
                    txtContent.append('\n');
                }
                br.close();


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("txtName", itemName); //pass the file name and  content to the second activity
                i.putExtra("txtContent",  txtContent.toString());//remember we added our second activity in manifest
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);

            }
            catch (IOException e) {}

        }

    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_activity1:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK);
            break;
        case R.id.setting_activity1:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i2, RESULT_OK);
            break;
        case R.id.about_activity1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coming soon ... :) ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }

    return true;
}


private void getOverflowMenu() {

    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            showUserSettings();
            break;

    }
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());

}


public void readTextFiles() {
    ArrayList<TextFile> textData = new ArrayList<TextFile>();

    Log.i("11111", "*********");
    File STR = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/testfiles");//sdcard directory->/mnt/sdcard
    if ( !STR.exists()) {
        STR.mkdir();
    }
    File myFolder = new File(STR.toString());
    //*****************************************

    File fileDir;
    StringBuilder txtContent = new StringBuilder();
    String txtName;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    TextFile tempFile = new TextFile();
    Log.i("22222", "*********");
    File[] myFiles = myFolder.listFiles();

    //*******************************************
    for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = myFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            txtName = file.getName().toString();
            fileDir = new File(STR + "/" + txtName);//reading the file contnt
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileDir));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    txtContent.append(line);
                    txtContent.append('\n');
                }
                tempFile = new TextFile(txtName, txtContent.toString());
                textData.add(tempFile);
                txtContent.delete(0, txtContent.length());//deleteing txtContent 
                br.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

    }

    TextFileAdapter adapter = new TextFileAdapter(this, R.layout.textfile_item_row, textData);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String backgroundColor = sharedPrefs.getString("backgroundColor", "#14a584");
    listView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));

    }
}
```

Anyone can explain a standard way to change the textcolor off a custom listview?

Thanks.

Comment: please post out error log

Comment: There is no `setTextColor()` in your adapter, please post error log also.

Comment: Where are you setting text color, put entire code and also put error log for your app close

Comment: please, post snippet code from 'MainActivity.java:235'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how can some one upvote this nullpointer question ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya I don't know but this is totally `NullPointer` because the OP have to only change the TextColor in `CustomAdapter`. and he or she couldn't be get the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution , dont know its normal way, but in this case worked for me. I did put the settextcolor in orverriden method of ArrayAdapter Class.

```
public class TextFileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TextFile> {

Context             context;
int                 layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<TextFile> data = null;


public TextFileAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<TextFile> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    TextFileHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new TextFileHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
        holder.txtContent = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemContent);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
       String textColor = sharedPrefs.getString("textColor", "#000000");
        holder.txtContent.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (TextFileHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    TextFile textFile = data.get(position);
    holder.txtContent.setText(textFile.content);
    holder.txtName.setText(textFile.name);

    return row;
}


    static class TextFileHolder
    {

        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtContent;

    }
}
```

Really thanks for your concern!